# Batch Closing before end of file?

Tags: batch-file, dos

I am trying to create a batch to automate commands for something. Right now I am just running a single command and the batch closes right after it prints the output from the command. I put a PAUSE in at the end but it keeps running past it. This is probably something very simple that I am just missing.

```
@echo
set /p ticket="Enter ticket number: "
tkt get %ticket%
PAUSE
```

The tkt get %ticket% part is from a custom utility I am using. That part is definitely formatted properly because I use it through command prompt every day almost. I want to automate a lot of my normal commands to make life easier.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `tkt get %ticket%` line? And you're sure you don't need to wrap `%ticket%` in quotes?

Comment: If it is removed the batch pauses properly, but without that line the batch is pointless because I want to automate input into the tkt utlity.

Comment: Try to call your tool  'call tkt' as it can stop your "main" batch if it's also a batch file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is "tkt" a batch file?  Try making it "call tkt" instead.

If you call a batch file from another, the first one will exit after executing the 2nd one, unless it is called with "call".

Here's an example:

**Foo1.bat**

```
foo2.bat
echo foo1
```

**Foo2.bat**

```
echo foo2
```

It seems like if you run Foo1.bat, it will spit out both "foo1" and "foo2" but it does not:

```
C:\temp>foo1

C:\temp>foo2.bat

C:\temp>echo foo2
foo2
```

To change the behavior, Foo1.bat should look like this:

**foo1.bat**

```
    call foo2.bat
    echo foo1
```

Comment: Yes tkt is also a batch file. Adding "call" worked perfectly. I knew it was my lack of understanding of the mechanics of batch files.