# Batch script is not executing another batch if I run from jenkins

Tags: batch-file, jenkins

I have installed Jenkins 1.55 exe in windows environment. I have a build script*.bat) which internally calls another (.bat). While executing manually it is working fine but while trying in jenkins only first batch script is executing without triggering the second one and it is giving as success.

Is there any solution for this?

---

D:\Jenkins\workspace\9.0_TP_Build>cd D:\PortalScripts\9000 portal\

D:\PortalScripts\9xxx portal>WL9.0-TPRefresh-doPortalNightlyBuild2.bat   ---> THis is the file i am executing

D:\PortalScripts\9xxx portal>cd d:\PortalScripts\axxx portal

D:\PortalScripts\9xxx portal>call WL-9000-TPRefresh-BuildPortal.bat a.x.x.x axxx axxx --> THis is the second file needs to be executed...but the below echo are from the first batc files...

D:\PortalScripts\9xxx portal>REM @echo off

D:\PortalScripts\9xxx portal>SET HR= 5

Comment: Try adding `echo on` for the calling batch file and see what it tries to call. Jenkins has its own environment and most likely you have paths issues. In general, it's always a good idea to use full paths to eliminate these kind of errors.

Comment: What code are you using to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you call a batch file from another, the first one will exit after executing the 2nd one, unless it is called with "call".  For example:

```
call WL9.0-TPRefresh-doPortalNightlyBuild2.bat
```

instead of just:

```
WL9.0-TPRefresh-doPortalNightlyBuild2.bat
```

There is a similar question/answer here, with an example: [Batch Closing before end of file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877695/batch-closing-before-end-of-file/7878377#7878377)

Comment: Yes John I am using call to execute my first script. and the 2nd script is not executing its content

Comment: Can you post the contents of your batch file (instead of the interactive commands you posted in your question)?

Comment: The below command executed from jenkins....i have not run this from the command line. If i do it in command line it is perfectly executing. But from the jenkins it is not